# How to split a variable in Perl on tab character?

Tags: perl

I have a variable `$results` generated by the following `foreach`loop

```
my $result = "";
foreach $c1(sort {$a<=>$b} keys %info ) {
    $result .= $c1 . "\t" .
      join(',',@{$info{$c1}->{var1}}) . "\t" . 
      join(',',@{$info{$c1}->{var2}}) . "\n";
}
```

If I print the results it looks like this

```
a    b    c
c    d    e
f    g    h
```

So there are three columns seperated by `\t` and the lines are separated by `\n`.
I now want to split this `$results` variable by tab, to end up with 3 columns. I tried to do this with a while loop, but it's not working

```
while($result){
    my @columns = split("\t"); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Without an argument, `split` splits the value of `$_`. You want `split(/\t/, $result);`

Also, the `while` looks wrong. Perhaps you want

```
for my $r (split (/\n/, $result)) {
    @columns = split (/\t/, $r);
    :
```

Answer (score 4):

What you have written will produce an endless loop, since `while ($result) { ... }` will continue as long as `$result` is a true value, which yours is. Furthermore, if you did split it as you wanted you would get

```
("a", "b", "c\nd", "e", "f\ng", "h", "i")
```

which I presume isn't what you want.

You shouldn't join all your data together with tabs and then split it again. Keep it as separate items. Something like

```
my @results;

foreach my $c1 (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %info ) {
  push @results, [
    $c1,
    join ',', @{ $info{$c1}{var1} },
    join ',', @{ $info{$c1}{var2} }
  ];
}
```

Then you will have an array of arrays corresponding to the originally printed data. You can print it out for diagnostic purposes using [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDump) if you wish.

---

**Update**

Since you want to retain the values of the first column, which are the sorted keys of the has, you may as well save those separately before looping over them. Perhaps this code suits you better?

```
my @keys = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %info;
my @results;

foreach my $c1 ( @keys ) {
  push @results, [
    $c1,
    join ',', @{ $info{$c1}{var1} },
    join ',', @{ $info{$c1}{var2} }
  ];
}
```

Now `@keys` is the list of values that you wanted.

Comment: OK, I understand what you mean. I was indeed producing an endless loop. But how can I now access the values of the first column? Since I need to compare them with values from another file.

Comment: You can collect the values of the first column using `my @first = map $_->[0], @results`. But it is looking like you are going a very long way round to get to your goal. I cannot help you better without seeing the bigger picture.

Comment: If you want a list of the values in the first column and nothing else then I wonder why you have included the `join` expressions in the first place? I have added an alternative solution to my answer that you may prefer.

Comment: @ Borodin Well my goal here is to compare the values of the first column to values in another table. If these values are the same than the values of the third column should be copied to the other table.